# Recording the image on a USB flash drive

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, flash

I have ISO-image as Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.04, and a flash drive 8Gb. How to burn a bootable USB flash drive for installation? I need a simple utility, where i choose the ISO file and USB flash drive, and nothing more ..)

Comment: Take a look at [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend UNetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/, it can create bootable USB for almost anything.